# Facebook share button on my app - Do I have to use the facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios5, ios6

I want to implement the simplest Share this button on my app that the user can tap and share that he is using the app on his Facebook wall. Do I have to integrate the facebook sdk in my app just for that?  I guess that there's an easy app doing that in iOS 6 and above but my app supports iOS 5 and up.

What are the consequences for using an HTML snippet or something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

inside a `UIWebview` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to user facebook sdk then you can user facebook graph API.

Comment: Yes in UIWebView. For more information http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support iOS5 & above versions, Then you need to implement Facebook SDK for providing the Facebook Share functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 5 use the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) for iOS6 use [SLRequest API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233).

I think this is the easiest and less trouble way to do it.

Comment: You repeated the question in a form of an answer